# Does a component need to disconnect from the socket io server after unmounting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have a React component that establishes a connection with a socket io server. When the component unmounts, should it automatically disconnect via a `useEffect`?

If yes, then what is the syntax to disconnect from a React component to Socket io server?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do it when you need Socket in other components. But I think you mean unbinding events, then Yes of course you need to unbind it.
BTW, if you want to disconnect, replace `socket.off` with `socket.disconnect` in the code below.
I use such this syntax:

```
function Helper() {
    const socket = useSocket; // my custom hook that returns a socket instance.

    useEffect(()=> {
          socket.emit("FOO_BAR", "BLA_BLA"); 
          socket.on("CALL_ME", handleCall); // handleCall is a cb somewhere in my code

          return () => {
                socket.off("CALL_ME", handleCall);
          }
    }, [socket]);
}
```